# Cannot find the error in my function header

Tags: python

Does anything in this line look off? I can't seem to find whats causing the error that's pointing towards the semi-colon.

```
def split_words(sentence: str) -> List[str]:
```

Comment: There's no semicolon in the line of code written.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: You need at least one more line for this to be valid code. And for `List` you'd need to include `from typing import List`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You've written `List` and not `list`.
Here is a minimum runnable code for your function.

```
def split_words(sentence: str) -> list[str]:
   return sentence

print(split_words("Hello world!"))
```

I leave you to write the body of the function that you need.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kendle said, in later versions of Python 3.x you can use this:

```
def split_words(sentence: str) -> list[str]:
```

Or, import `List` from `typing`:

```
from typing import List
def split_words(sentence: str) -> List[str]:
```